# How to power a high current / low voltage circuit through wall outlets?

Tags: power-supply, led-strip, high-current

I'm trying to wrap my head around this basic problem but I'm stuck here: I'm using 4 of [these LED strips](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B072N7VGK6) and I'm not sure how to safely power them.

They are rated at 18W/M, so 4 strips * 5m * 18W = 360W with an input voltage of 5VDC, meaning they would draw 72A if they all were lit at the same time. Let's say I only turn on 75% of them at once, the circuit would then draw 54A.

My understanding of wall outlets is probably wrong, but I read that they are rated at 15 or 20A. **Does that mean that I cannot use the same outlet to power this circuit?** If not, can I use  outlets on the same circuit or will I have to use separate lines from the circuit breaker? Or any other solution that I'm not aware of?

*Optional question:* Power converters that can output that much current are usually big, so I'm considering setting up 4 power converters in parallel all coming from the same power supply, is there any other potential issue I should be aware of if I choose this route?

Comment: Wiring them in series instead of parallel reduces current because you can make use of higher voltages to get the same amount of power.

Comment: But they are individually addressable so the data pin connection would not be simple to get level shifting; OK maybe an opto-isolator could do it..

Comment: You could use something like [this](https://www.amazon.com/SE-450-5-Power-Supply-Single-OUT-9-Pin/dp/B005T7MUR0) power supply. 5V, 75A, 375W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need 360W @ 5V. 200W 5V are fairly common, I would consider 2 of these. [https://www.amazon.com/SHNITPWR-Converter-Adapter-Transformer-WS2812B/dp/B07TSKK4FR/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07TSKK4FR)

Don't put them in parallel, run 2 strips on each.

The input *current* is not the same as the output *current*. The input *power* is more directly related to the output *power*, the output power is less due to inefficiency. If your power supply is 80% efficient, your input power would be 360W/80% = 450W. At 110 VAC this would be only 4 amps on your household outlet.

Comment: Thanks for this. Those adapters are quite big (size is problematic for my use). Could I use several smaller current output transformers @5V in parallel to power the LED strips?

Comment: No, not unless they are specifically designed to run in parallel, which is not very common. Parallel supplies will never have the exact same voltage and they will *fight* each other. It it better to split your strips into smaller pieces and run each from it's own power.

Comment: To the OP: Since you have 4 strips, maybe you could use 4 power supplies without any difficulty. One supply for each strip. Say 100W each. Be mindful of cooling. You can't just cram the supply in a tight space with no ventilation and expect everything to work out.

Comment: @garys - Harper (see his answer) is anticipating your next issue, 5V distribution. This will be a challenge, heed his advice.

Comment: Note that the LED drivers in the package use constant current drivers, varying the supply voltage has little effect on the current. This is important because it will allow considerable voltage drops on your wires before the brightness is affected.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's a misprint (or a deliberate mis-specification). Should 1.8W per meter.

My reasoning is as follows:

For the 5m roll, the connecting wires would not support 18A @5V they are just 1-2A capacity.

60 LED's per meter @ 18W means each LED is dissipating 300mW which would be OK on a PCB with some copper, but unless the tape  was stuck down on a metal surface, things would get too hot.

So maybe do a sanity check from other suppliers of similar items, and/or find one with a current rating.

Comment: I can confirm that each LED is 0.3 W. Sanity check: 5V * 20 mA * 3 LEDs = 0.3 W. My high density strip is 43 W per meter. Most have less density. They have power connectors on both ends, so the current can be divided by 2.

Comment: Description says 60 LED per meter. I had to measure power consumption on a strip very similar to that. With all LED's at max brightness, it was around 28mA at 5V per LED. Working from memory. Round it to 30mA, then it is 150mW per LED. If it is 60 LED per meter, then that is 9W per meter. If it is only 20mA, then that would still be 6W per meter.

Comment: I measured my strip with 10 LEDs illuminated at full brightness. The current is 350 mA, or 35 mA per LED. At 5V this would be 175 mW per LED. This is considerably less than the rating of 300 mW per LED. Some of this is due to tolerances, but I suspect that it is also to encourage people to buy power supplies with some margin.

Answer (score 0):

Wall outlets use higher voltage so 10A at 110VAC is 1.1 kilowatts. You just need a 72A 5V power supply which is only 360 watts. Or use several smaller 5V supplies.

Answer (score 0):

It's always tricky to guess at skill level of the asker.  But I'm concerned there are several skill areas where  you're going to need a lot of help, no offense.

We use a unit called "Watts" to measure useful power irrespective of voltage.

Watts = volts x amps.

Your load is 72A x 5V = 360W.  The common receptacle is good for 120V x 12A (continuous) = 1440W.   So it is simply a matter of power conversion.

As you notice, when volts go down, amps go up in proportion.

One thing that nobody's talking about is **voltage drop**.  This is where your design falls apart.  The curse of individually addressible LEDs is their need to run on a very low voltage, and being long linear strips.

Voltage drop is caused by Ohm's Law:  `Vdrop = A * R`   The resistance is decided by how thick the wires are. But you are hit by a double whammy when voltage is very low: Current is very high so *voltage drop* is very high: And, that voltage drop is taking a much bigger bite out of your total voltage.

Let's consider your 360W going through the 120V mains versus your 5V strips.   Let's say the wires have a resistance of 0.05 ohms.

> Mains: 360W is 3 amps @ 130V.  A*R = 3*0.05 = 0.15 volts drop.  So 120V becomes 119.85 volts. Drop is 0.125%.
>
> 5V: 360W is 72 amps @ 5 V.  A*R = 72*0.05 = 3.6 volts drop. So 5V becomes 1.4 volts. Drop is 72%. Whoops!

See, delivering 5 volts over the same wire simply does not work.  The wires must be much larger.

The built-in wires in these LED strips is not thick enough to do the job for 5 metres, let alone 20. They were never imagined to be used in a long string; you're thought to cut the string at the designated spot and use it for arrays.

So you will need to feed the strips at more frequent intervals than every 5 metres.  And you will need fairly thick feed wires if the LEDs are linear.

Right off the bat, a 72 amp supply will require mighty big copper, or at least mighty big aluminum.

So there are some real challenges with your setup.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation and no offense taken at all I'm a total noob  In the past I managed to power a 4-meter led strip @18W / meter (so 72W total) with a single power supply (5V/8A). But given your comment, that would mean a voltage drop of only 0.72V which I guess didn't impact the good functioning of the LEDs. One power feed every 5 meters should do it though. In that case I could use 4 of these 5V/8A power converters and connect them all to a multi plug adapter on the same wall outlet, correct?